# Реализовать список приложений в лаунчере

Tags: java, android, launcher

Каким способом можно реализовать список приложений так чтобы можно было их группировать и перетаскивать?

Comment: Я понимаю, вы свой launcher пишете? RecycleView, наверное. Вместе с ItemTouchHelper.

Comment: Да, все верно. Делаем корпоративный лаунчер. Вы не видели, может есть где-то простой пример реализации?

Comment: Про лончер ничего не знаю, а про перемещение элементов в RecycleView вот здесь читал: https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел вариант с использованием CellLayout кастом класс унаследованный от ViewGroup.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher/+/master/src/com/android/launcher/CellLayout.java